# jquery not working on select change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.mark').change(function(){
    var data= $(this).val();
    alert(data);
});
</script>

</head>
<body >

<select class='mark' required>
<option value='' disabled selected>Marketplace </option>
<option value='Amazon' >Amazon</option>
<option value='Flipkart' >Flipkart</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

i want to change placeholder of a input textfield on selection of option.but to do that first of all jquery should be called but above code is not working please suggest me something.
i want to change placeholder of a input textfield on selection of option.but to do that first of all jquery should be called but above code is not working please suggest me something.

Comment: you are include core jquery file?

Comment: no, what is core jquery file?

Comment: jquery core file is all code of jquery after include this file you can use jquery code otherwise it is not working check my answer

Comment: all below solution not working in my case.its working if i run it through run code snippet.one more thing im echoing form through php so may be that is the reason ?

Comment: no this is not affect you can paste your full code in question?

Comment: can u plz check again i just added full code

Comment: you can add jquery file?

Comment: i already added it while echoing form.see just above select tag.

Comment: this is not actual method to you can place jquery file to anywhere simply place this to before <script></script>

Comment: i did that before then since it was not working then i changed it

Comment: now again i changed it as u said but still not working

Comment: any console error?

Comment: no their is no error in console.again i updated question with only that selection part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use jQuery plugin

<select class='mark' required>
  <option value='' disabled selected>Marketplace </option>
  <option value='Amazon' >Amazon</option>
  <option value='Flipkart' >Flipkart</option>
</select>

Answer is
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mark").on("change",function(){
        var selected_value = $(this).val();  //get option tag value
        var selected_text = $(this).find(":selected").text(); // get option tag text
        alert(selected_value+" == "+selected_text); //print the result
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

might be you forgot add `jQuery` library, you can check following snippet for this

```js
$('.mark').change(function(){
 var data= $(this).val();
 alert(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='mark' required>
 <option value='' disabled selected>Marketplace </option>
 <option value='Amazon' >Amazon</option>
 <option value='Flipkart' >Flipkart</option>
</select>
```

Comment: even after adding library its not working. see question again

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine, check here. I think you forget to add the jquery library in your code.

```js
$('.mark').change(function(){
   var data= $(this).val();
   alert(data);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select class='mark' required>
  <option value='' disabled selected>Marketplace </option>
  <option value='Amazon' >Amazon</option>
  <option value='Flipkart' >Flipkart</option>
</select>
```

Comment: its not working in my case,its running when i click on run code snippet

Answer (score 0):

> Check This Perfectly Working!

```js
 $('.mark').change(function(){
   var data= $(this).val();
   alert(data);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='mark' required>
  <option value='' disabled selected>Marketplace </option>
  <option value='Amazon' >Amazon</option>
  <option value='Flipkart' >Flipkart</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$(document).on("change",".mark",function(){
   var data= $(this).val();
   alert(data);
 });
```

Comment: not working .may be because im echoing out form from php?

Comment: @ArjunSahani the above method is perfect for the dynamic created html. Simple .change method will not work. Please carefully look into this. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally do this:
HTML code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#mark1').change(function() {
    
      alert($(this).val());
    });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

  <select class='mark' required id='mark1'>
        <option value='' disabled selected>Marketplace </option>
        <option value='Amazon' >Amazon</option>
        <option value='Flipkart' >Flipkart</option>
    </select>

</body>

</html>
```